# sentencepiece library is not being installed in the system

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-wheel, automatic-license-plate-recognition, sentencepiece

While using `pip install tf-models-official` I found the following problem while the library is getting installed:-

```
Collecting tf-models-official
  Using cached tf_models_official-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.2 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tf-models-official) (9.0.1)
Collecting gin-config
  Using cached gin_config-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting seqeval
  Using cached seqeval-1.2.2-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow~=2.8.0 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tf-models-official) (2.8.0)
Collecting tensorflow-datasets
  Using cached tensorflow_datasets-4.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (4.2 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tf-models-official) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.19.1 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tf-models-official) (1.8.0)
Collecting pandas>=0.22.0
  Using cached pandas-1.4.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (10.6 MB)
Collecting py-cpuinfo>=3.3.0
  Using cached py_cpuinfo-8.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting google-api-python-client>=1.6.7
  Downloading google_api_python_client-2.42.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.3 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 8.3/8.3 MB 7.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: tf-slim>=1.1.0 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tf-models-official) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil>=5.4.3 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tf-models-official) (5.9.0)
Collecting tensorflow-hub>=0.6.0
  Using cached tensorflow_hub-0.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (108 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tf-models-official) (3.5.1)
Collecting kaggle>=1.3.9
  Using cached kaggle-1.5.12-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting sacrebleu
  Using cached sacrebleu-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (90 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.4 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tf-models-official) (1.22.3)
Collecting tensorflow-addons
  Using cached tensorflow_addons-0.16.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (755 kB)
Collecting oauth2client
  Using cached oauth2client-4.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
Collecting pyyaml<6.0,>=5.1
  Using cached PyYAML-5.4.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
Collecting sentencepiece
  Using cached sentencepiece-0.1.96.tar.gz (508 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting opencv-python-headless
  Using cached opencv_python_headless-4.5.5.64-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl (35.3 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: Cython in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tf-models-official) (0.29.28)
Requirement already satisfied: pycocotools in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tf-models-official) (2.0.4)
Collecting tensorflow-text~=2.8.0
  Using cached tensorflow_text-2.8.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (2.5 MB)
Collecting tensorflow-model-optimization>=0.4.1
  Using cached tensorflow_model_optimization-0.7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (237 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth<3.0.0dev,>=1.16.0 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official) (2.6.2)
Collecting google-api-core!=2.0.*,!=2.1.*,!=2.2.*,!=2.3.0,<3.0.0dev,>=1.31.5
  Using cached google_api_core-2.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (114 kB)
Collecting uritemplate<5,>=3.0.1
  Using cached uritemplate-4.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting google-auth-httplib2>=0.1.0
  Using cached google_auth_httplib2-0.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.3 kB)
Collecting httplib2<1dev,>=0.15.0
  Using cached httplib2-0.20.4-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from kaggle>=1.3.9->tf-models-official) (4.63.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from kaggle>=1.3.9->tf-models-official) (1.26.9)
Collecting python-slugify
  Using cached python_slugify-6.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.1 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from kaggle>=1.3.9->tf-models-official) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from kaggle>=1.3.9->tf-models-official) (2.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from kaggle>=1.3.9->tf-models-official) (2021.10.8)
Collecting pytz>=2020.1
  Using cached pytz-2022.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (503 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py>=2.9.0 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official) (3.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official) (58.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: gast>=0.2.1 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official) (0.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: flatbuffers>=1.12 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official) (2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: libclang>=9.0.1 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official) (13.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem>=0.23.1 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official) (0.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: opt-einsum>=2.3.2 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official) (3.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.9.2 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official) (3.19.4)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio<2.0,>=1.24.3 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official) (1.44.0)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-preprocessing>=1.1.1 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.4.0 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt>=1.11.0 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: keras<2.9,>=2.8.0rc0 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-pasta>=0.1.1 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: astunparse>=1.6.0 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official) (1.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: tf-estimator-nightly==2.8.0.dev2021122109 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official) (2.8.0.dev2021122109)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard<2.9,>=2.8 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.6 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official) (4.1.1)
Collecting dm-tree~=0.1.1
  Using cached dm_tree-0.1.6-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (91 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->tf-models-official) (3.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->tf-models-official) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->tf-models-official) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->tf-models-official) (21.3)
Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->tf-models-official) (4.31.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.0.5 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from oauth2client->tf-models-official) (0.2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa>=3.1.4 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from oauth2client->tf-models-official) (4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.7 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from oauth2client->tf-models-official) (0.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: tabulate>=0.8.9 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from sacrebleu->tf-models-official) (0.8.9)
Collecting regex
  Using cached regex-2022.3.15-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (274 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from sacrebleu->tf-models-official) (0.4.4)
Collecting portalocker
  Using cached portalocker-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting scikit-learn>=0.21.3
  Using cached scikit_learn-1.0.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (7.2 MB)
Collecting typeguard>=2.7
  Using cached typeguard-2.13.3-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting dill
  Using cached dill-0.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (86 kB)
Collecting promise
  Using cached promise-2.3-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting tensorflow-metadata
  Using cached tensorflow_metadata-1.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel<1.0,>=0.23.0 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from astunparse>=1.6.0->tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official) (0.37.1)
Collecting googleapis-common-protos<2.0dev,>=1.52.0
  Using cached googleapis_common_protos-1.56.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (241 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools<6.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<3.0.0dev,>=1.16.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official) (5.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from requests->kaggle>=1.3.9->tf-models-official) (2.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from requests->kaggle>=1.3.9->tf-models-official) (3.3)
Collecting threadpoolctl>=2.0.0
  Using cached threadpoolctl-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting joblib>=0.11
  Using cached joblib-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (306 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard-data-server<0.7.0,>=0.6.0 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.9,>=2.8->tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official) (0.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard-plugin-wit>=1.6.0 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.9,>=2.8->tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official) (1.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.9,>=2.8->tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official) (2.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.9,>=2.8->tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official) (3.3.6)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.9,>=2.8->tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official) (0.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=226 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from portalocker->sacrebleu->tf-models-official) (303)
Requirement already satisfied: text-unidecode>=1.3 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from python-slugify->kaggle>=1.3.9->tf-models-official) (1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<2.9,>=2.8->tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<2.9,>=2.8->tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official) (3.2.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: sentencepiece
  Building wheel for sentencepiece (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [22 lines of output]
      C:\Users\USER\Documents\Python Scripts\Number_Plate_Recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:717: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
        warnings.warn(
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\sentencepiece
      copying src\sentencepiece/__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\sentencepiece
      copying src\sentencepiece/sentencepiece_model_pb2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\sentencepiece
      copying src\sentencepiece/sentencepiece_pb2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\sentencepiece
      running build_ext
      building 'sentencepiece._sentencepiece' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src\sentencepiece
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\USER\Documents\Python Scripts\Number_Plate_Recognition\anprsys\include -IC:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\cppwinrt /EHsc /Tpsrc/sentencepiece/sentencepiece_wrap.cxx /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src/sentencepiece/sentencepiece_wrap.obj /MT /I..\build\root\include
      cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/MD' with '/MT'
      sentencepiece_wrap.cxx
      src/sentencepiece/sentencepiece_wrap.cxx(2809): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sentencepiece_processor.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for sentencepiece
  Running setup.py clean for sentencepiece
Failed to build sentencepiece
Installing collected packages: sentencepiece, pytz, py-cpuinfo, gin-config, dm-tree, uritemplate, typeguard, threadpoolctl, tensorflow-model-optimization, tensorflow-hub, regex, pyyaml, python-slugify, promise, portalocker, opencv-python-headless, joblib, httplib2, googleapis-common-protos, dill, tensorflow-metadata, tensorflow-addons, scikit-learn, sacrebleu, pandas, oauth2client, kaggle, tensorflow-datasets, seqeval, google-auth-httplib2, google-api-core, google-api-python-client, tensorflow-text, tf-models-official
  Running setup.py install for sentencepiece ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for sentencepiece did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [22 lines of output]
      C:\Users\USER\Documents\Python Scripts\Number_Plate_Recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:717: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
        warnings.warn(
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\sentencepiece
      copying src\sentencepiece/__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\sentencepiece
      copying src\sentencepiece/sentencepiece_model_pb2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\sentencepiece
      copying src\sentencepiece/sentencepiece_pb2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\sentencepiece
      running build_ext
      building 'sentencepiece._sentencepiece' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src\sentencepiece
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\USER\Documents\Python Scripts\Number_Plate_Recognition\anprsys\include -IC:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\cppwinrt /EHsc /Tpsrc/sentencepiece/sentencepiece_wrap.cxx /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src/sentencepiece/sentencepiece_wrap.obj /MT /I..\build\root\include
      cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/MD' with '/MT'
      sentencepiece_wrap.cxx
      src/sentencepiece/sentencepiece_wrap.cxx(2809): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sentencepiece_processor.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> sentencepiece
```

Hence, figured the problem might lie with sentencepiece. Hence, tried installing sentencepiece with two commands `pip install sentencepiece` as well as `pip install sentencepiece==0.1.92`. However the following error is coming:-

```
   Collecting sentencepiece
  Using cached sentencepiece-0.1.96.tar.gz (508 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: sentencepiece
  Building wheel for sentencepiece (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [22 lines of output]
      C:\Users\USER\Documents\Python Scripts\Number_Plate_Recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:717: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
        warnings.warn(
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\sentencepiece
      copying src\sentencepiece/__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\sentencepiece
      copying src\sentencepiece/sentencepiece_model_pb2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\sentencepiece
      copying src\sentencepiece/sentencepiece_pb2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\sentencepiece
      running build_ext
      building 'sentencepiece._sentencepiece' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src\sentencepiece
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\USER\Documents\Python Scripts\Number_Plate_Recognition\anprsys\include -IC:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\cppwinrt /EHsc /Tpsrc/sentencepiece/sentencepiece_wrap.cxx /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src/sentencepiece/sentencepiece_wrap.obj /MT /I..\build\root\include
      cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/MD' with '/MT'
      sentencepiece_wrap.cxx
      src/sentencepiece/sentencepiece_wrap.cxx(2809): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sentencepiece_processor.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for sentencepiece
  Running setup.py clean for sentencepiece
Failed to build sentencepiece
Installing collected packages: sentencepiece
  Running setup.py install for sentencepiece ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for sentencepiece did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [22 lines of output]
      C:\Users\USER\Documents\Python Scripts\Number_Plate_Recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:717: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
        warnings.warn(
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\sentencepiece
      copying src\sentencepiece/__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\sentencepiece
      copying src\sentencepiece/sentencepiece_model_pb2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\sentencepiece
      copying src\sentencepiece/sentencepiece_pb2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\sentencepiece
      running build_ext
      building 'sentencepiece._sentencepiece' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src\sentencepiece
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\USER\Documents\Python Scripts\Number_Plate_Recognition\anprsys\include -IC:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\cppwinrt /EHsc /Tpsrc/sentencepiece/sentencepiece_wrap.cxx /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src/sentencepiece/sentencepiece_wrap.obj /MT /I..\build\root\include
      cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/MD' with '/MT'
      sentencepiece_wrap.cxx
      src/sentencepiece/sentencepiece_wrap.cxx(2809): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sentencepiece_processor.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> sentencepiece

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I have already tried to see if wheels is installed through `pip install wheels` and

```
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in c:\users\user\documents\python scripts\number_plate_recognition\anprsys\lib\site-packages (0.37.1)
```

I have tried to find a solution to this but to no avail.

Answer (score 12):

`sentencepiece` is a library that requires binary extensions and thus has to package individual wheels for each operating system, CPU architecture and Python version. From the above logs, it seems that you are using CPython 3.10 on Windows AMD64. Looking at the available [wheels on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/sentencepiece/#files), there is no one for this platform yet. Only Python versions from 3.6 to 3.9 have Windows wheels for now.

This means you either have to downgrade to Python 3.9, or build `sentencepiece` from source.

Comment: Update: They now provide Python 3.10 wheels for Windows. However, as of Apr 1 2023, Python 3.11 wheels aren't available for any platform yet.

Comment: Thanks!, v3.11 has been throwing up errors all day long

Comment: And as of May 2023 they have wheels for 3.11. But as of today (Feb 12 2024) none for 3.12